# GWT MouseClickEvent vs MouseDownEvent

Tags: gwt

Is there a standard way to separate MouseClick and MouseDown events in GWT?

If I click and hold button I still get MouseClick event together with MouseUp.

if I just click I still get MouseDown event together with MouseClick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These events have some differences. Handle events which you need in a particular situation.

The thing is that in a general case `ClickEvent` includes `MouseDownEvent` and  `MouseUpEvent`  and cannot take place without of them. `MouseDownEvent` and `MouseUpEvent` precede `ClickEvent`. The same way as `ClickEvent` precedes `DoubleClickEvent`. But `MouseDownEvent` doesn't garantee that an `ClickEvent` will occur.

- `MouseDownEvent` occurs every time when a user presses on one of the mouse buttons inside any element.
- `MouseUpEvent` occurs when a user releases one of any mouse buttons.
- and `ClickEvent` consists of both of these events. `ClickEvent` occurs when there're both these events on the same element. It's something like a combination of the mouse down and mouse up events. `ClickEvent` is generated only for the left mouse button unlike `MouseDownEvent` and `MouseUpEvent`.

That's `ClickEvent` is generated when a mouse is down then up while over an elem.
However, the mouse must stay within the same element, otherwise it won't occur.

For example, you pressed mouse down and moved outside of the element and release it. `ClickEvent` will not generated but `MouseDownEvent` will in this case.

And if you press mouse down and move outside the element, and move back in, then release it. `ClickEvent` will occur. And `MouseDownEvent` with `MouseUpEvent` will too.

If a user did click then this is the sequence of events:

1. MouseDownEvent
2. MouseUpEvent
3. ClickEvent

`ClickEvent` fires only after a user has released his mouse button.

Butt there's a way to create `ClickEvent` without generating of `MouseDownEvent` and `MouseUpEvent`:

- click event will fire if a user used tab key to move the focus to a link and press Enter, but the MouseDown and MouseUp events will not.

Alternatively, you can open a link without generating `ClickEvent`:

- click right button on a link and select on a item of dropdown list (in this case only `MouseDownEvent` and `MouseUpEvent` will fire)
- also you can  just pick up and drag a link to a new tab